# How to forward domain to Cloudfront URL without showing target URL in browser?

Tags: dns, subdomain, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have a domain which I want to redirect to a AWS cloud front URL.

If I only add a redirect at my domain provider then browser shows the cloud front URL in address bar which looks ugly.

I can create a CNAME record with the cloud front URL to a sub-domain, but not directly to the domain, but I do not want user to type the complete sub-domain name.

I tried adding a combination of (1)a redirect from domain to the sub-domain and (2) a CNAME record from that sub-domain to the cloud-front URL. But, of course, I get "too many redirects".

What is the correct solution for this? Will any Route53 service fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the name server on my DNS to AWS route-53 ones and then added a record to the Alias pointing to my cloud-front distribution. In Cloud-front, I had to set my domain name as the Cname.

An alternate solution, and effectively another way to create virtual record, could have been as discussed [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/why-cant-a-domain-s-root-be-a-cname-8cbab38e5f5c/) in "The Solution" section. Unfortunately my domain registrar(1&1) doesn't support this feature.

[Edit 06/27] I tried CloudFlare's CNAME flattening feature and that works as well.